# How to get the text value from textbox within a FormView from ascx file in the ascx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, textbox

I have an asp: text box in an FormView in an ascx file like this>

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="myFrmView">

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox1" size="20" MaxLength="150" >

</FormView>
```

But in the code-behind ascx.cs file I can't retrieve the value from the textbox

```
string name2 = Request.Form["txtBox1"];
```

How to get the value?

Comment: this will get it from the Server side based on the value that was posted another sweet trick `string name2 = Request.Form[txtBox1.UniqueID];`

Comment: Chris_45 I would suggest editing your question.. you have left many confused here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found it.

```
string value = (myFrmView.FindControl("txtBox1") as TextBox).Text;
```

What was the thing was the inside a FormView control and that had no id. Id of myFrmView

Comment: This is the correct answer when inside a formview or listview template.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `Request`, you should be able to access the control directly in the code behind, try:

```
var value = txtBox1.Text;
```

Comment: No message> The name txtBox1 does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Even though it is in the ascx file and trying to get in in the ascx.cs file.

Comment: @Chris_45 that means you don't have `runat="server"` in the markup for the control - or the control isn't inside a `<form>` element with `runat="server"`.

Comment: @Chris_45 like Mike said, ensure you have runat="server"

Comment: look at his code.. he has runat="server" in his initial posting

Comment: It is inside runat="server" in both the form and the markup for the control. But it is an .ascx file not an .aspx. But that shouldn't matter?

Comment: Chris - try to use this code here and see if it works ..also show where you are trying to get the value do you have a button click...etc.. `string name2 = Request.Form[txtBox1.UniqueID];` what is the scope of name2 when you are trying to use it.. create a property instead and test / store the value that way..

Comment: @Chris_45 if it is in a seperate user control then reference the control then the component.  I.e. userControl.txtBox1.Text;

Answer (score 1):

Access control directly:

```
string text = txtBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's txtBox1.Text. ASP.NET doesn't generate HTML elements with the same names you gave them in your markup file IDs, and referencing Request.Form is a bypass of the robust object model that supports the server-side controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the control directly with txtBox1.text, then I would check to make sure your ascx file is pointing to the correct code behind file in the <% @Page %> section at the top.  There should be a CodeBehind attribute pointing to your [file].ascx.cs.

You may also want to check to make sure that the declared class in your ascx.cs matches the one in the designer.cs file.  If they don't, the partial class declaration in the designer.cs won't match and you won't have the properties for your controls.

I'll get this error if I manually rename some files and forget to update the code behind attribute.

Comment: Does the declared class name in your designer.cs match the ascx.cs?

Comment: Yes but I had to change it, but same error with > 'The name doesnt exist in the current context'